# Jenkins Pipeline: How to build job build after multibranch project is built?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to define `Build after other projects are built` for Pipeline **Multibranch**, especially for org. folders like **GitHub Organization** or **Bitbucket Tream/Project**?

Example:

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([upstream(
        threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS,         
        upstreamProjects: "../multibranch-job/master")])])
```

Does it work? Does it require absolute or relative path?

Comment: Have you tried it already?

Comment: @StephenKing Apparently I had a problem with relative path and special characters.

Answer (score 12):

Apparently `Build after other projects are built` works just fine either with generic Pipeline, Multibranch, or Org. Folders like Bitbucket Team/Project.

My problem was related to the fact that I was referring to job with incorrect path.

### Absolute Path:

An absolute path could be always found out in the upper section of job screen. This is especially useful if name contains special characters which might be replaced by Jenkins.

[image]

Thus the `properties` step should look:

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([upstream(
        threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS,         
        upstreamProjects: "t/multibranch-job-to-be-triggered/feature%2Ftest")])])
```

### Relative Path:

Beside absolute path, you can refer to job with relative paths, ex:

- `another-branch`
- `../another-job/branch`

Comment: It didn't work for me: It gives me the following error:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticField hudson.model.Result SUCCESS

Comment: It worked after approving the field in "In-process Script Approval" page